# How to make a good impression in a large organisation?

Tags: work-environment, work-experience

I do not have much experience working for large organisations; I have left University exactly a year ago and have been working at a start up ever since. I have since found a new job doing graphic design/marketing related tasks at a new organisation, however this is company is much larger then I had expected and the job seems a little above my pay grade: Basically there seems to be an expectation of higher level of independence and communication (communication with stakeholders and people inside the office). I am terrible at talking to people, however I do have the skills.

So I guess my question is how does an introverted IT person succeed at a large organisation?

And Generally hwat are some tips of working at bigger ocmpanies?

Comment: There's entire books written on this man. Just too much to put in one answer here.

Comment: Now is a good time for you to decide that you always wanted to be good at talking to people :) Your capabilities should never be static.

Comment: One way is to avoid ever sending something like this in an email: And Generally hwat are some tips of working at bigger ocmpanies?

Comment: `I am terrible at talking to people, however I do have the skills` what does this mean? For example, I am terrible at drawing landscapes, although I do have the skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are some tips for working at bigger companies?

(I am answering this from the perspective of someone that is used to working in smaller companies, as the OP states.)

Realize that **large companies have more process**. They need it because there are more people involved and each person needs to understand how they contribute to the whole. Whereas in a small company you may be used to making your own way, you need to play with the team in a large company, even if sometimes things take longer or are harder.

You will probably want to make process changes. By all means raise suggestions but **take time to learn the processes and their history before you push for change**. The biggest mistake you can make in a large company is repeating someone else's mistake. Processes often affect many people, so understand the ramifications of changes for everyone, not just yourself.

**Know who is responsible for what areas or decisions**. Beyond knowing the decision makers, it also gives you a broader perspective and will make you better at your job. Similarly, make friends outside your immediate group or team. It is easy to know everyone in a small company, even people outside your role such as HR and IT. It is much harder in a larger company.

When working in a larger team, you need to **communicate more frequently and effectively**. Make sure your boss and peers know what you are doing and you have what you need from them - do not wait for your boss/project manager/scrum master/whatever to find out for you. Use the best communication tool for the job: sometimes a short conversation in a stand up meeting or a Wiki post is better than an E-mail.

On the bright side, **bigger companies offer more opportunities then small ones**. There are more teams and projects you can be transferred to, bigger networking opportunities and are more likely to be recognized by recruiters and future hiring managers.

> How does an introverted IT person succeed at a large organisation?

The same way you do in a small organization: **do good work and get on well with people**. However, that is not what you are asking.

All this can be challenging for an introvert. The key is to **start small and not do all this at once**. Wait until you are comfortable with your team then expand a little at a time. Also, remember to give yourself some "cave time". For example, if you find yourself stressed because your day is full of meetings, book out some time to yourself in your calendar. Book a meeting room where you can sit quietly and just get some work done or re-energize for a while.